# How can I create list of sections that a command appears in?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a modular document that specifies the following command;

```
\newcommand{\specify}{A block of warning text}
```

I need to include at the end of the document a list of references for every section that the `\specify` command appears.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an elementary implementation that collects the placement of `\specify` in the form of a reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multido}
\newcounter{warningtext}
\newcommand{\specify}{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{warningtext}\label{warningtext-\thewarningtext}% Capture reference
  A block of warning text%
  \par
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \section{Warning text locations}
  \begin{itemize}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\value{warningtext}}{\item Section~\ref{warningtext-\i}; page~\pageref{warningtext-\i}}
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-15]\specify\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful!  I note that the `10` here controls how many result items it will show.  Is there any way to have this 10 be dynamic rather than static?  ie: the actual amount of occurences?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams: I've updated the answer to reflect that using `\value{warningtext}` instead of a fixed `10`.

Comment: You sir, are a boss.